# How to compare each date within a vector of dates to another date

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a vector of dates, and I want to find out which of those dates fall within a certain interval of dates. For example:

```
library(lubridate)

df$dates <- c(ymd("1999-1-1", "2000-1-1", "2001-1-1"))
comparison_interval <- interval(ymd("2000-12-25"), ymd("2005-1-1"))
```

I want to compare the vector to the stated interval to see which of the dates in that vector are within the interval. Ultimately I want a boolean vector that I can put in the data frame. So in the example above, I would want a vector of FALSE, FALSE, TRUE. I have tried using %within%

```
df$dates %within% comparison_interval
```

But it returns an error saying "Argument 1 is not a recognized date-time." What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue `c(ymd("1999-1-1", "2000-1-1", "2001-1-1")) -> v1;v2 <- interval(ymd("2000-12-25"), ymd("2005-1-1"));v1 %within% v2#
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: I realize now the problem may have been with my data. Regardless, Kelsey solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this as a boolean expression:

```
dates <- c(ymd("1999-1-1", "2000-1-1", "2001-1-1"))
results <- dates >= ymd("2000-12-25") & dates <= ymd("2005-1-1")
```

This would give you a logical vector.